# Nested Queries with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a following schema with 3 tables

| user_table |
| --- |
| id |
| domain_id |

| domain_table |
| --- |
| id |
| organization_id |

| organization_table |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

Given user_id from user_table , I want to get name from organization_table, a typical sql will be "SELECT name FROM organization_table WHERE id = (select organization_id from domain_table WHERE id = user_id)

How do we do it in sqlalchemy ORM?

Comment: This query can be rewritten as an inner join, no need for a subquery.